# Adobe Edge: control a specific symbol from html page

Tags: jquery, adobe-edge

I need to control over one of my edge Symbols, from my **HTML page** (index.html - not the edgeActions.js page)

For example, I have an image Symbol: "sym1", and I want to hide it from the main html page.
I tried:

sym.$( "sym1" ).hide();

But it doesn't work..

That's the only way I could make it work (In edgeActions page only):

```
  Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, "document", "compositionReady", function(sym, e) {
         var ex1 = sym.$( "sym1" );         

         yepnope({
            both: [
                "libs/jquery-ui.min.js",
                "libs/jquery-ui.css",
            ],
            callback: function() {

         ( ex1 ).hide();
            }
         });

      });
```

I need to understand how can I control the symbol from the main html page with JQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grabbing symbols when you're outside of the edge program require you to do a bit more than call "Symbol."  So let me just walk you through how to grab your symbol:

`1st` - You have to get a reference to the specific composition.  This will generally be the class on the #Stage element.  If you don't give it a specific name in Edge Animate, the default name will be something weird like EDGE-1230930194.

```
var myAnim = AdobeEdge.getComposition("nameOfComposition");
```

`2nd` - You need to grab the specific symbol

```
var mySymbol = myAnim.getSymbols("nameOfSymbol")[0]; // Because it's in an array
```

And there ya have it!  You got yourself the symbol.  If you wanted to play it in reverse for example then you'd do this:

```
mySymbol.playReverse();
```

The more interesting things to do for finer manipulation involve grabbing the underlying element like so:

```
var mySymbolElem = mySymbol.getSymbolElement();
```

And then of course you can use any jQuery methods to mess around with it:

```
mySymbolElem.fadeOut(5000, function(){alert("alerts rox")});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Will you please have look on [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14453079/1036917) and give me suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After Edge render to html page, all symbol will be merge with a new id name are connected by an "_". For example if you want to change an image of a symbol named "thumb01":

```
$('#Stage_thumb01').css('background-image',  'url('thumb_img_02.jpg')');
```

"Stage" is a root default container of an Edge html