# How to bindElementAction with class elementSelector in Edge Animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, adobe-edge

I am trying to play my stage when I hover over a `<button class="play">`.  I have not created this button in Adobe Edge Animate.

This is what my code looks like:

```
Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, symbolName, ".play", "mouseenter", function(sym, e) {
         sym.play();
});
```

This doesn't work at all, but if I replace `".play"` with something like `"document"` or `"div"` it works fine (not `"button"` though for some reason).

I've also tried `"$(.play)"` and `"$('.play')"` with no success.

How can I target a class to bind an action to?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer elsewhere.

You can access the symbol by doing:

```
var myComp = AdobeEdge.getComposition("compositionname");
var mySymbol = myComp.getSymbol("symbolname");
// var myStage = myComp.getStage(); if all you want is the stage
```

Then you can do things like:

```
$(".play").mouseenter(function(e) {
  mySymbol.play();
});
```

Source [Adobe Edge: control a specific symbol from html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556152/adobe-edge-control-a-specific-symbol-from-html-page?rq=1)